# Aggregation query from two tables

Tags: sql, mongodb, subquery

We have a schema:

```
stores:
{_id , name}

getways: 
{_id, store_id }

txes:
{tx_id,getway_id}
```

A store has many getways, and getway has many txes.

We need count of txes for specific store.

SQL:

```
SELECT count 
FROM   txes 
WHERE  getway_id IN (SELECT _id 
                     FROM   getways 
                     WHERE  store_id = xxxx)
```

How can I write it in mongo query?

I write this query in jaspersoft studio mongo query.

Comment: I do not know jaspersoft however, MongoDB doesnot yet support server-side subqueries

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that mongodb supports relational sub queries. You need to use Database references(**Manual References or DBRefs**) to accomplish your task.

Check out this link.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/

Comment: Database references are entirely client side, no support for getting the references within the database itself